# Multiple markers Google Map API v3 from array of addresses using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to implement the multiple markers functionality from array of addresses using angular js.

Here is my fiddle :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cVsdp/175/
```

But i'm getting the following error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the JSFiddle setting from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`

[image]

See the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cVsdp/179/

**Edit:**
Also, change the line

```
map = new google.maps.Map(angular.element(document.querySelector("#map_canvas")[0]), myOptions);
```

to the following:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

The working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cVsdp/180/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for  replying ztan. After changing onLoad to No wrap - in <body> console.log("latlng" + latlng); is displaying the values. But still map is not displaying.. and in console it is displaying  error message---------------------------->Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.. Could you please help me..

Comment: @javadeveloper, please see my edited answer. Also,would you mind marking it as accepted (green check mark) if it solves your problem?

Comment: Hi Ztan could you pls give solution for this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705263/using-angular-modal-service-displaying-multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-a

Answer (score 0):

so many examples on internet, but in most of the examples latitude and longitude is already available in those databases.

The following example takes array of address and put multiple markers on google map.

The working  example :

`jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/cVsdp/182/`